# How to set the checked values in jquery multiselect asp dropdownlist

Tags: jquery, asp.net, jquery-ui

i have used this script for the jquery multiselect in that i am getting  values in the array based on the values in the array it should be checked in the jquery multiselect..

asp dropdownlist id:**ddlDepartment**

**hdnDepartment** in this hidden field i will get all the values which is been checked

```
$(document).ready(function () {
            var revalue = new Array();
            if (document.getElementById("<%=hdnDepartment.ClientID %>").value != "") {
                var str = document.getElementById("<%=hdnDepartment.ClientID %>").value;
                var obj = $("#<%=ddlDepartment.ClientID %>");
                alert(obj);
                revalue = str.split(',');
                var i;
                for (i = 0; i < revalue.length; i++) {
                  //should reload that values in the checked in jquery multiselect 
                }

            }
        });
```

Comment: So hdnDepartment is a hidden input with true,true,false,false? Comma seperated

Comment: Since you've anyway included jQuery, you might as well make your code shorter and cleaner by using `$('#X').val()` in place of `document.getElementById('X').value`

Comment: @techfoobar - he needs to do it this way as classic asp will append a random ID to the element and therefore it cannot be accessible this way. I would surround the hidden element in a div with an id and call it with $('#divID input[type="hidden"]).val(); This way the element will never be confused

Comment: i am getting the value sin the hidden feild i have kept alert and checked

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put hdnDepartment in a surrounding div

```
<div id="departmentCheck">
      <input type="hidden" value="true,true,false,false" id="hdnDepartment" />
</div>
```

and the jquery should be

```
$(document).ready(function () {
   var revalue = new Array();

    if ($('#departmentCheck input').val() != "") {

        var str = $('#departmentCheck input').val();
        revalue = str.split(',');
         var counter=0;

         $('#idOfMultiselect option').each(function(k,v){

            try{

               //if catch if there is no index at counter in revalue then default to false
               $(v).attr('checked', revalue[counter]);


             }
             catch{
                $(v).attr('checked',false);

             }

            counter++;

           });


            }
        });
```

Comment: i have used <asp:HiddenField ID="hdnDepartment" runat="server"></asp:HiddenField>

Comment: in that case i can use that itself a?

Comment: Either wrap it in a div to allow jquery to easily identify it due to asp.net adding a random string to the id of the element, therefore jquery will not be able to pick up "hdnDepartment" as asp will make it "adadki394939020hdnDepartment"

Comment: your script has some error in closing tags can you check it and revert me plz

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, you don't need to surround the hidden element by an element. The way you got the element was almost correct; you missed an hash (i.e. '#') in the selector.

Assuming you're using jQuery 1.6+, I believe the following code will resolve your question:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var values = $("#<%=hdnDepartment.ClientID %>").val();
    $.each(values.split(','), function(i, val) {
        $("#<%=ddlDepartment.ClientID %> option").eq(i).prop('checked') = (val === 'true');
    });
});​
```